# itext lowagie version:'2.1.7' will support the chinese trasulations for pdf

Tags: pdf, itext

i am using itext lowagie version:'2.1.7' i can translate franch, spanish, and italy etc in pdf export.
but chinese simplified and chinese traditional cannot translate in PDF.

Comment: As you don't show the pivotal code. we obviously cannot point out what you do wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look in our glas ball: Most probably you are missing the additional itext-asian.jar which contains all the necessary cmaps etc.

https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=iTextAsian

So e.g. this would work if you use maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cn.lesper</groupId>
    <artifactId>iTextAsian</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or alternatively if you are able to [find](http://123.232.10.234:8212/nexus/content/groups/public/com/lowagie/itextasian/1.5.2/) it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextasian</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```